# Stream Data from SQL Server into Redshift with Kinesis Firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis-firehose

The tool below is a batch import method of copying data from SQL Server RDS into Redshift.

[AWS Schema Conversion Tool Exports from SQL Server to Amazon Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/05/aws-schema-conversion-tool-exports-from-sql-server-to-amazon-redshift/)

Is there a more streamlined  method, conducting every second way of streaming data from MS SQL Server into Redshift with Kinesis Firehose. I know we can move AWS Aurora SQL directly into Redshift with Kinesis.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you use Amazon Kinesis? Or is your goal simply to move data from SQL Server to Amazon Redshift?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to move data from Microsoft SQL Server into Amazon Redshift, then you could consider using [AWS Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/). It can copy data as a one-off job but can also migrate on a continuing basis.

See:

- [Using a Microsoft SQL Server Database as a Source for AWS DMS - AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.SQLServer.html)
- [Using an Amazon Redshift Database as a Target for AWS Database Migration Service - AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Redshift.html)